# Two toggle switch at the local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to try the dark mode switch for laptop and mobile. So, I used two toggles and also used local storage. I have a problem. In two toggles, only work first toggle for dark mode.  I want to run two toggle switches at the same time. When I want to switch on, another toggle also switches on automatically.

> `HTML`

```
 <li><a id="sidebar-a">Darkmode
<input type="checkbox" id="switch"><label class="label2" for="switch">Toggle</label>

<li><a id="sidebar-a">Darkmode
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch2"><label class="label6" for="switch2">Toggle</label>
```

`CSS`

```
  body.light {
                --body-back: #F7F7F8;
               
                --h1-color: #42493e;
                --a-color:#39393A;

                --setting-tool:#696969;
                --quick-bar:#E5E5E5;
             
                --quick-bar2:#dee4e7;
              
      
            }
    
            body.dark{
                --body-back:#0e0e10;
                
                --h1-color:orange;
                --a-color:#dfdfe1;

             
                --quick-bar:#464649;

          
                --quick-bar2:#37474f;
              
            
            }
    
            body{
                background: var(--body-back);
            }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    







    
    
            input[type="checkbox"]{
                height: 0;
                width: 0;
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            .label2{

enter code here

                cursor: pointer;
                text-indent: -9999px;
                width: 46px;
                height: 23px;
                background: #c4c4c4;
                display: block;
                border-radius: 100px;
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: 124px;
                margin-top: -37px;
        
            }
            .label2::after{
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 2.4px;
                left: 2.5px;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                background:#34393f ;
                border-radius: 90px;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }
     
    
            input:checked + .label2{
                background: black;
            }
            input:checked + .label2::after{
                left: calc(100% - 2.5px);
                transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
    
            input:checked + .label6{
                background: black;
            }
            input:checked + .label6::after{
                left: calc(100% - 2.5px);
                transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
            .label6{
                cursor: pointer;
                text-indent: -9999px;
                width: 46px;
                height: 23px;
                background: #c4c4c4;
                display: block;
                border-radius: 100px;
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: 124px;
                margin-top: -37px;
        
            }
            .label6::after{
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 2.4px;
                left: 2.5px;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                background:#34393f ;
                border-radius: 90px;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }










const chkToggle = document.querySelector("#switch")
const theme = localStorage.getItem("theme")

document.body.classList.toggle(theme === "dark" ? "dark" : "light")

if (theme == "dark"){
    chkToggle.checked = true
}

else {
    chkToggle.checked = false
}

chkToggle.addEventListener("change", function (e){

    e.preventDefault()
    if (this.checked) {
        document.body.classList.add("dark")
        document.body.classList.remove("light")
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark")
        console.log("dark mode");
    }
    else{
        document.body.classList.add("light")
        document.body.classList.remove("dark")
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "light")
        console.log("light mode"); 
    }
})
```

**It doesn't work**

Comment: Are you wanting both toggles to have the same data when switched? As in click one of the toggles and they both flip to dark mode?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Can you modify my code.

Comment: @Micah Johson Can You help me?